# VS Code Pylance stopped highlighting

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

Recently Pylance stopped highlighting any variables or modules. Do you have any idea how to fix it?

I tried changing python.languageServer, reinstalling Python and Pylance extensions in VS code, using older version but got no luck.
I am using Python 3.11.3, latest vs code versions[image]

Comment: Have you selected the python interpreter? Could you run the python script success?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution. I just change theme of VS code and it worked